# add option fields between <select> and </select>

Tags: javascript

I have a day <SELECT> field and a month <SELECT> field, and the day <SELECT> should contain the month's days number of <OPTION>s. for exemple if I choose April from month <SELECT> the number of <OPTION>s in the day <SELECT> is 30. My question is: how can I add an <OPTION> field between the <SELECT> and </SELECT>?

this is the HTML code:

```
<div class="input">
    <label>Date de naissance</label>
    <br>
    <select name="jour"></select>
    <select name="mois" onchange="ajouterJours(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);"></select>
    <input type="number" name="annee">
</div>
```

and this is the JS script I've created so far:

his is the function which gonna work on the load of the page :

```
function main()
{
    var i = 0;
    var moisSelect = form.mois;
    while (i<12)
    {
        i++;
        moisSelect // here I cant figure out what to do with the month SELECT to add options
    }
}
```

And this is the function which add options between <SELECT> and </SELECT> for the day <SELECT> field:

```
function ajouterJours(mois)
{
    var mois = 0;
    var jourSelect = form.jour;
    switch(mois)
    {
        case 1,3,5,7,8,10,12:
            mois = 31;
            break;
        case 2:
            mois = 29;
            break;
        case 4,6,9,11:
            mois = 30;
    }
    var i = 0;
    while (i<m)
    {
        i++;
        jourSelect  // here I cant figure out what to do with the day SELECT to add options
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing your own instead of using a date picker widget like [jQuery's](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/datepicker/) which is localized to a variety of languages including (at the risk of assuming too much from variable names) French?

Comment: As incentive not to write your own, you're miscounting February's days.

Comment: I can't use it, we studied only javaScript

Comment: no I'm preparing for an exam and I'm doing some exercises from the net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic code to add one element as a child of another looks like this:

```
// i assume this has already been done
var select = <get your select element here>;
...

var option = document.createElement('option');
option.value = "the value";
option.appendChild(document.createTextNode('The Label'));
select.appendChild(option);
```

The code to remove one is as simple; in fact, to remove the last one, it's trivial.

```
select.removeChild(select.lastChild);
```

The simplest code i can come up with off the top of my head to determine the number of days in a month (while properly accounting for leap years):

```
function daysInMonth(month, year) {
    if (!month) month = (new Date()).getFullYear();
    var lastDay = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month % 12, 1) - 1);
    return lastDay.getDate();
}
```

So now, consider the problem.  You want to make the number of options match the number of days in the month when the month changes.  In pseudocode:

```
on month change:
    newNumberOfDays = daysInMonth(selected month, selected year)
    while current number of options =/= newNumberOfDays:
        if newNumberOfDays > current number of options
            add an option for (current number of options) + 1
        else
            remove the last option
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add new option elements to a select like this:

```
select.options[index] = new Option(text, value);
```

Also you can clear a select by setting the `length` property to `0`

Here is a working example for your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/inti/KTJMA/

HTML

```
<select name="mois"></select>
<select name="jour"></select>
```

JS

```
var select_mois = document.getElementsByName("mois")[0];
var select_jour = document.getElementsByName("jour")[0];

select_mois.length = 0;
for (var m=0; m<12; m++) {
    select_mois.options[m] = new Option(m+1, m+1);
}
select_mois.onchange = function() {
    var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
    addJour(val);
}
select_mois.onchange();

function addJour(m) {
    var days = daysInMonth(m, (new Date()).getFullYear())
    select_jour.length = 0;
    for (var j=0;j<days;j++) {
        select_jour.options[j] = new Option(j+1, j+1);
    }
}

function daysInMonth(month, year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}
```